# Python: Convert Quill delta to HTML

Tags: python, django, quill, weasyprint

My existing project is using [quill.js](https://quilljs.com/), And a sample quill content(delta) will look something like this

```
{
  "ops": [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "underline": true,
        "bold": true
      },
      "insert": " dfsdfdsf "
    },
    {
      "insert": "\n"
    }
  ]
}
```

Are there any pure python ways to convert these content into HTML?. I need this as a part of report generation to PDF on the server side using [WeasyPrint](http://weasyprint.org/).

**Note: Kindly do not attempt to answer if you haven't used Quill.js before, or at least know what it is.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If want to plain HTML in order to submit it to your server (for the entire edited document), you can just grab `quill.root.innerHTML` (which is the HTML inside the quill edit box) when your form is submitted (when the Submit button is pressed).

```
<form action="/SomeAction"
      method="POST"
      onsubmit="this['contents'].value = quill.root.innerHTML;"
      name="contentForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="239" />
    <input type="hidden" name="contents" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Bit counter-intuitive, that's what I did finally, send the quill delta to the browser, Use a dummy div and generate the HTML and transport it back to the server. Somewhat it works. Wish similar project existed as a Python module. https://github.com/UmbraEngineering/quilljs-renderer. Kudos and releasing the bounty :p